# Splice data in array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a project on data mapping. Several checks are realized:

- well imported file
- table choice
- columns choice of the table
- typage of data

I'm for at the part of the choice of columns for the moment. I'm stocking these various choices in an array. The problem is that if I want to delete one choice in my array, all data are deleted !
I'm using this plugin: http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/multiple-select/docs/

```js
var choiceFields = [];                  
$('#selectFields').multipleSelect({
    filter: true,
    onClick: function(view) 
    {
        choiceFields.push(view.value);
        var length = choiceFields.length-1;
        if(view.checked === false)
        {
            choiceFields.splice(view.value);
        }
        console.log(choiceFields);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://rawgit.com/wenzhixin/multiple-select/master/multiple-select.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/wenzhixin/multiple-select/master/multiple-select.js"></script>
<div class="select-box">
    <label for="selectFields"><span class="label-FieldChoice">Choice fields</span>  </label>
    <select id="selectFields" multiple="multiple" style="display: none;">
        <option value="id">id</option>
        <option value="username">username</option>
        <option value="username_canonical">username_canonical</option>
        <option value="email">email</option>
        <option value="email_canonical">email_canonical</option>
        <option value="enabled">enabled</option>
        <option value="salt">salt</option>
        <option value="password">password</option>
        <option value="last_login">last_login</option>
        <option value="confirmation_token">confirmation_token</option>
        <option value="password_requested_at">password_requested_at</option>
        <option value="roles">roles</option>
        <option value="lastName">lastName</option>
        <option value="firstName">firstName</option>
    </select>
    
</div>
```

Comment: Note if `view` is your `<select>` element then `view.value` is going to be some word string not an integer which is what `splice()` expects the first argument to be. This is going to therefor end up effectively being `splice(0)` which removes all elements from the original array

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. Do not edit this answered question into a completely new question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
var choiceFields = [];
$('#selectFields').multipleSelect({
  filter: true,
  onClick: function(view) {
    choiceFields.push(view.value);
    var length = choiceFields.length - 1;
    if (view.checked === false) {
      choiceFields = jQuery.grep(choiceFields, function(value) {
        return value != view.value;
      });
    }
    console.log(choiceFields);
  }
});
```

I've changed:

```
choiceFields.splice(view.value);
```

to:

```
choiceFields = jQuery.grep(choiceFields, function(value) {
  return value != view.value;
});
```

**Demo**

```js
var choiceFields = [];
$('#selectFields').multipleSelect({
  filter: true,
  onClick: function(view) {
    choiceFields.push(view.value);
    var length = choiceFields.length - 1;
    if (view.checked === false) {
      choiceFields = jQuery.grep(choiceFields, function(value) {
        return value != view.value;
      });
    }
    console.log(choiceFields);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://rawgit.com/wenzhixin/multiple-select/master/multiple-select.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://rawgit.com/wenzhixin/multiple-select/master/multiple-select.js"></script>
<div class="select-box">
  <label for="selectFields"><span class="label-FieldChoice">Choice fields</span>  </label>
  <select id="selectFields" multiple="multiple" style="display: none;">
    <option value="id">id</option>
    <option value="username">username</option>
    <option value="username_canonical">username_canonical</option>
    <option value="email">email</option>
    <option value="email_canonical">email_canonical</option>
    <option value="enabled">enabled</option>
    <option value="salt">salt</option>
    <option value="password">password</option>
    <option value="last_login">last_login</option>
    <option value="confirmation_token">confirmation_token</option>
    <option value="password_requested_at">password_requested_at</option>
    <option value="roles">roles</option>
    <option value="lastName">lastName</option>
    <option value="firstName">firstName</option>
  </select>

</div>
```

Comment: No problem @Maestro Happy to help

Comment: Do you have an idea of how I can manage to get all values pushed in array if select all checkbox is checked @Carsten? I tried to add one more function (onCheckAll), specified in documentation, but it's returning me that view is undefined !

Answer (score 1):

In `Array.splice()` it takes 3 parameters  `array.splice(index, howMany, [element1][, ..., elementN])` .

**index** − Index at which to start changing the array.

**howMany** − An integer indicating the number of old array elements to remove. If howMany is 0, no elements are removed.

**element1, ..., elementN** − The elements to add to the array. If you don't specify any elements, splice simply removes the elements from the array.

But you had'nt provied `howMany` parameter in your answer provide this value to delete particular index from array

ex -

```js
var choiceFields = [];                  
$('#selectFields').multipleSelect({
filter: true,
onClick: function(view) 
{
   
    var length = choiceFields.length-1;
    if(view.checked === false)
    {
        var index = choiceFields.indexOf(view.value);  // Finding Index of Item

        choiceFields.splice(index,1);   // Splicing one element from index
    }
    else{
     choiceFields.push(view.value);  // if false we do not push value
    }
    console.log(choiceFields);
},

onCheckAll: function() 
{
     
     
     choiceFields = [];    // delete all previous values
     var options = document.getElementById('selectFields');
     for(var i=0;i<options.length;i++){
        choiceFields.push(options[i].text);
     }
   
   console.log(choiceFields);

}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://rawgit.com/wenzhixin/multiple-select/master/multiple-select.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/wenzhixin/multiple-select/master/multiple-select.js"></script>
<div class="select-box">
    <label for="selectFields"><span class="label-FieldChoice">Choice fields</span>  </label>
    <select id="selectFields" multiple="multiple" style="display: none;">
        <option value="id">id</option>
        <option value="username">username</option>
        <option value="username_canonical">username_canonical</option>
        <option value="email">email</option>
        <option value="email_canonical">email_canonical</option>
        <option value="enabled">enabled</option>
        <option value="salt">salt</option>
        <option value="password">password</option>
        <option value="last_login">last_login</option>
        <option value="confirmation_token">confirmation_token</option>
        <option value="password_requested_at">password_requested_at</option>
        <option value="roles">roles</option>
        <option value="lastName">lastName</option>
        <option value="firstName">firstName</option>
    </select>
    
</div>
```

Comment: Not sure it working correct, If i select Id, then Username and remove Username, then I get 2 times Username in the array

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen i've updated the answer now the requirement is acheived using array.splice()

Comment: Thank u also @Amit!! :)

Comment: Do you have an idea of how I can manage to get all values pushed in array if select all checkbox is checked @Amit? I tried to add one more function (onCheckAll), specified in documentation, but I don't know how to manage that?

Comment: Sure, I updated my code above. But, based on documentation, the function doesn't except parameters...

Comment: @maestro see the onCheckAll method of mine is it fulfliing your Requirement ?

Comment: So simple solution!! Thx again dude!! :D