# mapping data in different tables choice

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

I'm working on a project on data mapping. Some details are explained in other subject :
[Splice data in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52810658/splice-data-in-array)
Concerning recovery of select values, I'm using JQuery to stock them in array.

When these values are recovered, I would like according to mapping choice, complete existing table. The problem is that how can I detect number of columns before insertion in database.

This following error returned to me every time :

> **SQLSTATE[21S01]: Insert value list does not match column list: 1136 Column count doesn't match value count at row 1**

Query result :

> PDO->prepare('INSERT INTO gestion (firstName,lastName,mail) VALUES
>   (\'test\',\'jean\',\' marc\',\'marc\')')

```js
var choiceFields = [];
var contentChoiceFields = [];
$('#selectFields').multipleSelect({
    filter: true,
    onClick: function(view) 
    {    
        choiceFields.push(view.value);
        var length = choiceFields.length - 1;
        if (view.checked === false) 
        {
            choiceFields = jQuery.grep(choiceFields, function(value) 
            {
                return value !== view.value;
            });
        }
        contentChoiceFields = choiceFields;
        console.log(contentChoiceFields);
        $('.selectChoiceFields').val(contentChoiceFields);
    },
    onCheckAll: function() 
    {
        /*var contentSelect = "";
        $('#selectFields').each(function()
        {
            contentSelect = $(this).val();
            choiceFields.push(contentSelect);

        });
        contentChoiceFields = contentSelect;*/
        choiceFields = [];    // delete all previous values
        var options = document.querySelector('#selectFields');
        for(var i=0;i<options.length;i++)
        {
            choiceFields.push(options[i].text);
            contentChoiceFields = choiceFields;
        }
        $('.selectChoiceFields').val(contentChoiceFields);
    },
    onUncheckAll: function() 
    {
        choiceFields = [];
        $('.selectChoiceFields').val('');
    }
});

$(".mapping").on('click', function(event) {
    var data = [];
    var mapping = $(this).closest('th').text();
    $('th input:checked').each(function(index,element) {
        var currentCell = element.parentNode;
        $('td:nth-child(' + (currentCell.cellIndex+1) + ')').each(function(i,el) {
            if($(el).text().match(/^([a-zA-Z]+)(\d+)([a-zA-Z]+)$/))
            {
                data.push("'" + $(el).text() + "'");
            }
            else if($(el).text().match(/^(\d+)/))
            {
                var value = parseInt($(el).text());
                data.push("'" + value + "'");
            }
            else
            {
                data.push("'" + $(el).text() + "'");
            }
        });
    });
    var content = data;
    console.log(content);
    $('.choiceData').val(content);
});
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/wenzhixin/multiple-select/master/multiple-select.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/wenzhixin/multiple-select/master/multiple-select.css">


  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="select-box">
      <label for="selectFields"><span class="label-FieldChoice">Choice fields</span></label>
      <select id="selectFields" multiple="multiple" style="display: none;">
        <option value="id">id</option>
        <option value="username">username</option>
        <option value="username_canonical">username_canonical</option>
        <option value="email">email</option>
        <option value="email_canonical">email_canonical</option>
        <option value="enabled">enabled</option>
        <option value="salt">salt</option>
        <option value="password">password</option>
        <option value="last_login">last_login</option>
        <option value="confirmation_token">confirmation_token</option>
        <option value="password_requested_at">password_requested_at</option>
        <option value="roles">roles</option>
        <option value="lastName">lastName</option>
        <option value="firstName">firstName</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <table class="table table-striped table-hover" id="tableContent">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th>lastName<input name="lastName" class="mapping" id="lastName" type="checkbox">
          </th>
          <th> firstName<input name="firstName" class="mapping" id="firstName" type="checkbox">
          </th>
          <th> âge<input name="âge" class="mapping" id="âge" type="checkbox">
          </th>
          <th> phoneNumber<input name="phoneNumber" class="mapping" id="phoneNumber" type="checkbox">
          </th>
            <th> mail<input name="mail" class="mapping" id="mail" type="checkbox">
            </th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
          <td class="mappingContent">test</td>
          <td> marc</td>
          <td> 21</td>
          <td> 0265412369</td>
          <td> marc.test@bla.fr</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td class="mappingContent">jean</td>
           <td>marc</td>
           <td>28</td>
           <td>0692123456</td>
           <td>marc.jean@orange.fr</td>
         </tr>
       </tbody>
     </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
if($choiceMapping === "completion")
{
    if($session->get('tableChoice') == "user")
    {
        $password = password_hash('test', PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
        $content = $cnx->prepare("INSERT INTO ".$session->get('tableChoice')." "."(".$selectChoiceFields[0].", enabled, password, roles, lastName, firstName) VALUES (".$choiceData.",1, '".$password."', 'a:1:{i:0;s:1:\"0\";}', 'test', 'test')");
        $content->execute();

        $addFlash = $this->addFlash('success', "Completed recording !");
    }
    else
    {
    $content = $cnx->prepare('INSERT INTO '.$session->get('tableChoice').' ('.$selectChoiceFields[0].') VALUES ('.$choiceData.')');
        $content->execute();

        $addFlash = $this->addFlash('success', "Completed recording !");
    }
}
else
{
    $content = $cnx->prepare('Truncate '.$session->get('tableChoice'));
    $content->execute();

    $sql = $cnx->prepare('INSERT INTO '.$session->get('tableChoice').' ('.$selectChoiceFields[0].') VALUES (:choiceData)');
    $sql->bindValue(':choiceData', $choiceData);
    $sql->execute();

    $addFlash = $this->addFlash('success', "Completed recording !");
}
```

result of $selectChoiceFields :

> array(1) { [0]=> string(15) "firstName,lastMail,mail" }

result of $choiceData :

> string(30) "'test','jean',' marc','marc'"

Comment: Hmm, in PDO prepare I see you're trying insert 4 values in 3 in DB.

Comment: Yeah, I know, that's why I'm asking how to detect number of rows to adapt insertion in database?

Comment: Do you have access to DB? Use `DESCRIBE *YOUR_TABLE_NAME*` to get list of rows. However, you should know structure of DB tables before insertion

Comment: Yeah, I have access to DB. and I'm using this instance to get content of tables : https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/2.8/reference/schema-manager.html#schema-manager

Comment: I meant direct access, not through php abstractions. It's very handy to have direct access to DB. Without basic knowledge of common db operation it will be very hard to work with DB